# Problema al relacion modelos con sequelize / postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize

Estoy intentando relacionar mi modelo Users con el modelo Posts, quiero que el usuario al crear un post se guarde la id del post en el campo de array 'posteds' del modelo usuario, logro que se guarde la id del post en el array pero no puedo relacionarlos y tengo problemas al utilizar include para obtener toda la información del array posteds, espero que me haya explicado bien, gracias de antemano.

Creación de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    img_url TEXT,
    created_by UUID NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);    


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    role TYPE_ROLES NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER_ROLE',
    posteds uuid[],
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

Modelo Users:

```
import { DataTypes, UUIDV4, Optional, Model} from "sequelize"
import { connection } from "../database"
import { hash, genSalt, compare } from "bcryptjs";
import Posts from "./posts.model";

export const rolesEnum: string[] = ['ADMIN_ROLE', 'MODERATOR_ROLE','USER_ROLE']

interface UserAttributes{
    id: number,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    role: 'ADMIN_ROLE' | 'MODERATOR_ROLE' | 'USER_ROLE',
    posteds: Array<number>;
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at?: Date
}


interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id" | "created_at" | "posteds"> {}
// We need to declare an interface for our model that is basically what our class would be
interface UserInstance
  extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>,
    UserAttributes {}


const Users = connection.define<UserInstance>('users', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: UUIDV4
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        values: rolesEnum,
        defaultValue: 'USER_ROLE',
        allowNull: false
    },
    posteds: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY({
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        }),
        defaultValue: [],
        allowNull: false
    },
    created_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    }
},{
    timestamps: false
})


Posts.belongsTo(Users, {
    foreignKey: 'created_by_id',
    as: 'created_by_dates'
})

Users.hasMany(Posts,{
    foreignKey: 'posteds'
})


export default Users
```

Modelo Posts:

```
import { DataTypes, Optional, Model,  UUIDV4} from "sequelize";
import {connection} from "../database";

interface PostAttributes {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    description: string,
    img_url?: string,
    created_by_id: string,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at?: Date
}

interface PostCreationAttributes extends Optional<PostAttributes, "id" | "created_at"> {}
// We need to declare an interface for our model that is basically what our class would be
interface PostInstance
  extends Model<PostAttributes, PostCreationAttributes>,
    PostAttributes {}


const Posts = connection.define<PostInstance>('posts', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: UUIDV4
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    img_url: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    created_by_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    },
    created_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    }
},{
    timestamps: false
})



export default Posts
```

Funcion al crear el posts (inserto la id del usuario que creo el post al array posteds)

```
export async function createPost(req: Request, res: Response){
    try{
        const {title, description, img_url} = req.body

        const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1] || ''
        if(token == '') throw new Error()
        const created_by_id = jwt_decode<MyToken>(token).id

        const newPost = await Posts.create({
            title,
            description,
            img_url,
            created_by_id
        })

        const created_by = await Users.findByPk(created_by_id)
        const oldPosts = created_by?.getDataValue('posteds') || []
        oldPosts.push(newPost.id)
        await created_by?.save({
            fields: ['posteds']
        })
        
        
        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: 'true',
            message: newPost
        })

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        return res.status(500).json({
            ok: 'false',
            message: 'unexpected error'
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguien tenia el mismo problema les cuento la solución que encontré; al parecer tenia errores en la creación de las tablas, lo solucione sincronizando los modelos a la base de datos con el metodo sync() de sequelize.